# Testing species association and clustering : Multivariate analyses / weighted association test

Tags: statistics, clustering

Sorry to take a bit of your time but I am slightly (very) lost, and very unsure as to which test to use in R. Alright so here is the oversimplified sampling procedure, with easy-looking numbers :

-We have 20 patches of the same size in a field. -Inside these patches, we look for 50 different species (10 species of grass, and 40 species of insect) -Every time we find a species of grass, we record its coverage on a rough logarithmic scale from 1 to 4. -Every time we find a species of insect, we count them and record their abondance on a rough logarithmic scale from 1 to 4.

So my data sort of looks like this : [simplified extract][1]

My problem is, how do I test which species are significantly associated? How do I detect clusters? Multivariate analysis? Half weight index? Bootstrap?

I'm not exactly gifted when it comes to statistics, so any help would be greatly appreciated!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFAp8.jpg

Comment: You should ask the stats stackexchange, quite sure there are biostats experts there

Comment: Thanks, I did ;)